# What is the command-line interface used by GitHub Actions on Windows 10?

Tags: github-actions

I have an error when I use `&&` oprerator on `windows-latest` in my GitHub action workflow and I don't kwon why. I don't have this error on `ubuntu-latest`.

What is the command-line interface used by GitHub? Is it `cmd`? Is it `PowerShell`?

*Error message*

```
Run cd ./test && mkdir build && cd ./build && cmake -G"Unix Makefiles" ./..
At D:\a\_temp\7d2f0062-3ec5-48db-9ed0-235006d396e6.ps1:2 char:11
+ cd ./test && mkdir build && cd ./build && cmake -G"Unix Makefiles" ./ ...
+           ~~
The token '&&' is not a valid statement separator in this version.
At D:\a\_temp\7d2f0062-3ec5-48db-9ed0-235006d396e6.ps1:2 char:26
+ cd ./test && mkdir build && cd ./build && cmake -G"Unix Makefiles" ./ ...
+                          ~~
The token '&&' is not a valid statement separator in this version.
At D:\a\_temp\7d2f0062-3ec5-48db-9ed0-235006d396e6.ps1:2 char:40
+ cd ./test && mkdir build && cd ./build && cmake -G"Unix Makefiles" ./ ...
+                                        ~~
The token '&&' is not a valid statement separator in this version.
+ CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParseException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidEndOfLine
```

This is my GitHub action workflow :

*BuildJob.yml*

```
name: C/C++ CI

on: [push]

jobs:
  Linux-job:
    name: Run unit tests on Linux
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v1
    - name: CMake
      run: cd ./test && mkdir build && cd ./build && cmake -G"Unix Makefiles" ./..
    - name: make
      run: cd ./test/build && make
    - name: execute tests
      run: ./test/build/Test.out

  Windows-job:
    name: Run unit tests on Windows
    runs-on: windows-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v1
    - name: CMake
      run: cd ./test && mkdir build && cd ./build && cmake -G"Unix Makefiles" ./..
    - name: make
      run: cd ./test/build && make
    - name: execute tests
      run: ./test/build/Test.out
```

**Edit:**

Moreover when I'm compile with make on Linux, my include like

```cpp
#include "StatisticAnalysis.hpp"
```

has become case sensitive, weird...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As described [here](https://github.blog/changelog/2019-10-17-github-actions-default-shell-on-windows-runners-is-changing-to-powershell/), it is powershell but you can change this.

As you see [here](https://help.github.com/en/actions/automating-your-workflow-with-github-actions/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idsteps), you can create a multi line command:

```
- name: make
  run: |
    cd ./test/build
    make
```